# How to get the zipkin version

Tags: curl, microservices, zipkin

Is there any CURL to get the latest available zipkin version and another CURL to get the currently running version in my local environment ?

I have to do a version comparison on currently running Zipkin version with related to the latest available. I even walked through all the issues raised in github and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who could come across with a same scenario like this,

**github** has given **APIs** to get details on the repository tag set of each project release as a json object (https://api.github.com/repos/openzipkin/zipkin/tags ). So that can be used to get the latest version of zipkin.

To get the currently running version of my system, zipkin has given an actuator/info end point (http://localhost:9411/actuator/info).